# Weapon w = new Weapon(42); Isso está correto?

Tags: programação-estruturada

Teve esta questão numa prova de programação 
Considere a classe Abstrata Weapon. A linha de código abaixo apresenta algum erro? Justifique sua resposta.

```
Weapon w = new Weapon(42);
```

Essa é a minha resposta e o prof nao considerou nada
sim, não pode ter valor dentro de Weapon

o correto seria como está aqui em baixo /

```
Weapon w = new Weapon( );
```

Comment: A pergunta é se a linha está correta? se `Weapon` é abstrata nem tem como instanciar logo... vou de `NDA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade os dois modos estão incorretos pois uma classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada. Uma classe abstrata (no caso Weapon) é somente um modelo de classe que outras classes herdarão.